# Semantic patches for POSIX shell script

Tags: shell, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Is there a tool for refactoring using **semantic patches** for *shell scripts*, just like [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) for C?

An example modification would be to switch from

```
command > file
```

syntax to "sticky" one

```
command >file
```

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a tool for refactoring shell scripts?* I doubt it.

However, you could build one using a general [program transformation system (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

These are tools that accept language descriptions (you'd need a grammar for POSIX shell scripts), will parse said langauge building ASTs, and then allow you to apply transformations to those ASTs, finally prettyprinting the AST back to valid source text.

Good PTSes let you express code changes using source code patterns (Cocinelle is not a genearl purpose PTS since it only works for C, but it falls into this category of source-pattern driven) rather than writing procedure code to modify the trees.

A problem with most of them is they do not go beyond matching on (context-free) ASTs, while real constraints require the tool to understand "context" (e.g., how information from far away in the source text affects the meaning of a particular point in the text).   Cocinelle also does this, which is why it is an interesting tool; this kind of capability is *necessary* to transform traditional programming languages.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is a general PTS that provide support for context analysis (symbol tables, control and data flow analysis, ...).  I think (Unix) shell scripting langauge like Posix, all have various macro like capabilities that make processing them much harder than macro-free langauges such as Java.  DMS provides built-in support for capturing and handling preprocessor conditionals and macros; it presently uses these to handle C and C++.

But, a Posix transformation is not out of the box.  You have to define its grammar, and the various context analysis support to DMS.   At that point you can start to write context-dependent transformations using source patterns.  This work is doable with DMS, but isn't a weekend exercise.  So the real question is,

*how much automated patching do you intend to do; is it enough to justify configuring a PTS?*